# How to assign height of two dynamic div equal at run time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two div one is on left side and another is on right side and these are creating at run time the inner text of both. my problem is that how to make the both div height equal .
i am using code

```
$('#div_Set_1_ChannelRoomContent').height($('#div_ChannelRoomName').height());
```

but it does'nt work

Answer (score 3):

Why not do this?

```
var newHeight = Math.max($("#div1").height(), $("#div2").height());
$("#div1").height(newHeight);
$("#div2").height(newHeight);
```

If you're using floats, and the height doesn't have to be 'stretched' (with that I mean that the only thing that matters is that the next item is under both divs) you can just use the css property `clear: both;`.

Comment: $("#div1").height() is giving value 0

Comment: i am creating div at run time var newHeight = Math.max($(div1).height(), $(div2).height());
$(div1).height(newHeight);
$(div2).height(newHeight);

Comment: @JainNavneet What kind of element is it? A block/inline/inline-block/etc.?

Comment: And you might want to ensure you're using `$(window).load(function () { /* your code */ });` instead of `$(document).ready(/*...*/);` or `$(/*...*/);`, the last two are identical. They're both called before everything is completely done (like loading images). This is normally desired, but in some cases (like this one) it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Heard of the equalHeights plugin?

http://filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div id="main" style="width: 100%; height: 100px;">
    <div id="left" style="float: left; width: 49%; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
    <div id="right" style="float: left; width: 49%; height: 100px; border: 1px solid blue;"></div>
</div>
```

script:

```
$('div#left,#right').css("height", "220px");
```

using **jquery** you can dynamically change *height*

Comment: @Prashanth For the same reason you used bad grammar, it's easy, careless and everybody understands :D

Answer (score 0):

You should add css style unless you want to set the height dynamically.

css

```
#set1, #set2{
   float: left;
   min-height: Xpx;
   height: Xpx;
}
```

Markup:

```
<div id="set1">Blah blah</div>
<div id="set2">blah blah</div>
```

It depends on your markup structure but you might want to clear the float and set width if needed.

Comment: but i can not fix the height of any div not left nor right because at the run time the data is changing and height change....

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the rest of your code looks like but the line you wrote should work:

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">some text </div>
<div id="div2">some text...</div>
```

CSS:

```
#div1{
  height: 60px;    
  float: left;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var height = $("#div1").height();       
$("#div2").height(height);
```